# Problems of preloading fonts and images using gatsby and netlify

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, gatsby, preload, netlify

I am keep getting the warning message of my website: https://www.selectchu.com

chrome warning message

**"The resource was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate as value and it is preloaded intentionally."**

The resource https://www.selectchu.com/component---src-pages-index-js-e3609fd82d452154463c.js was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate as value and it is preloaded intentionally.
The resource https://www.selectchu.com/google-fonts/s/roboto/v19/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxK.woff2 was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate as value and it is preloaded intentionally.
The resource https://www.selectchu.com/app-97f530f3e5a7162dfd06.js was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate as value and it is preloaded intentionally.
The resource https://www.selectchu.com/webpack-runtime-c108f36890d85c65bb96.js was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate as value and it is preloaded intentionally.

**what can be the main problem? and how to solve it?**

I've tried to add as attribute on helmet plugin such as

```
const Font = 'public/google-fonts/s/roboto/v19/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxK.woff2'

require("dotenv").config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
})

module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `SelectChu`,
    description: `Upcoming SelectChu project`,
    author: `@Hogyster`,
  },
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-netlify',
      options: {
        allPageHeaders: [`Link: <${Font}>; rel=preload; as=font; type=font/woff2 crossorigin=anonymous`],
      },
```

this is my gatsby-config.js

```
plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    `gatsby-plugin-styled-components`,
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-transition-link`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-prefetch-google-fonts`,
      options: {
        fonts: [
          {
            family: `Noto Sans KR`,
            subsets: [`latin`, 'korean'],
            variants: [`400`, `700`]
          },
          {
            family: `Open Sans`,
            variants: [`400`, `700`]
          },
          {
            family: `Roboto`,
            variants: [`400`, `700`]
          },
        ],
      },
    },
    'gatsby-transformer-remark',
}
```

Comment: did u solve this ?